# 2 ways of freeing memory of a simple linked list in C? 

Tags: c, memory, free

**strong text**I created a linked list in C called lon with the help of following functions:

```
struct ilist_node {
   struct ilist_node * rest;
   int first;
};

typedef struct ilist_node *ilist;


ilist icons(int in, ilist il) {
   ilist r = malloc(sizeof(struct ilist_node));
   r->first = in;
   r->rest = il;
}
```

then I incremented the list with *icons* to create a list of numbers

after that, I tried to print each element in the list and free the memory used by the list by

```
while (lon!= NULL) {
      ilist tmp = lon->rest;
      printf(" %d\n",lon->first);
      free(lon);
      lon = tmp;
   }
```

I can understand why this function above works. (I googled how to free memory and this one seems to be the popular answer). But out of curiosity, I tried another one:

```
   ilist tmp = lon;
   while (lon != NUll) {
      printf(" %d\n",lon->first);
      lon = lon->rest;
   }

   idelete(tmp);
```

and it also works. So I'm a little confused. If the last one works, then why do I need to go through the list and free every node?

Comment: It isn't clear whether you want a comment on looping through the list, or freeing its space. If I assume idelete is really what we need to compare, then please post the source of idelete too

Comment: ahhh thank you. yep its because im using idelete given by my prof instead of the built-in delete. stupid mistake

Comment: As is often the case, asking the question helps!-)

Comment: @user1248785: Please look a little around, and read the FAQ, and so on. Don't write `(solved)` in front of your headline - nobody does so. Accept the answer (as you did) and upvote, if you have enough reputation to do so. Editing your question pops it up on the list. Just using the voting system is enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until I can see the source code for `idelete`, I can't comment. 
At the risk of being a PITA I don't think anyone can accurately comment.

We need the source for `idelete`.

`idelete` may be

```
void idelete(ilist il) {
   while (il!= NULL) {
      ilist tmp = il->rest;
      free(il);
      il = tmp;
   }
}
```

which would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Should `idelete()` implement the semantics you use in the first example (`free()`ing while iterating through list elements), everything should be freed. So if `idelete` knows about the `ilist` type and is capable of calling the `free` internally for the list elements (passing the list entry) you are fine and no leaks will occur.

However, if that is not the case my original statement below (and the other answers) apply:

---

The second one will literally only free the last/first element (depending how you consider the order of elements in the linked list) - the one you assigned with `ilist tmp = lon` at the top. It works, but it will leak some memory.

If this is on Linux or a unixoid system supporting it, I strongly suggest to check out what Valgrind with its default tool `memcheck` says about the whole thing, so you will likely learn something.